# Upload Image error: User is not authenticated, please authenticate using Firebase Authentication and try again

Tags: swift, swiftui

My application is logged in via anonymous authentication, I have a class on `SwiftUI` for uploading a user's photo from an iPhone, however, when uploading a photo to `Firebase` storage, I get the error:

> User is not authenticated, please authenticate using Firebase
> Authentication and try again.

Here's my code:

`AuthViewModel.kt`:

```
class AuthViewModel: NSObject, ObservableObject {

@Published var userID = ""


func login() {
    
    Auth.auth().signInAnonymously { (res, err) in
        
        if err != nil {
            print(err!.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        
        print("Success = \(res!.user.uid)")
        self.userID = res!.user.uid
        
    }
}
```

}

`UserViewModel`:

```
func setCurrentUserImage(profileImage: UIImage) {
    
    guard let imageData = profileImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.3) else { return }
    
    let filename = NSUUID().uuidString
    
    let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("UserPhotos").child("\(self.currentUser)/\(filename)")
    
    storageRef.putData(imageData, metadata: nil) { _, error in
        if let error = error {
            print("Upload Image error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }
        
        storageRef.downloadURL { url, _ in
            
            guard let profileImageURL = url?.absoluteString else { return }
            
            let docRef = self.db.collection("users").document(self.currentUser)
            
            docRef.getDocument(source: .cache) { (snap, err) in
                
                guard let curUser = snap else { return }
                
                curUser.reference.updateData(["userImage" : profileImageURL])
                
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

Firebase storage security rules:

```
match /{allPaths=**} {
  allow read, write;
}
```

Comment: And you’re seeing the success print line after authentication? Are you positive that the write command is starting after the auto has completed?

Comment: Yes, authentication works successfully and I see the user's uid, reading from storage also works fine, the write command is also launched